# default type argument and default argument in typescript 3.6

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Ever since upgrading to typescript 3.5, I am plagued with the same error message, I do not understand:

I have this react component

```
export const RouteWrapper = function RouteWrapper<
  P = { children?: ReactNode },
  TRoute extends RouteProps = Route
>(
  Wrapper: React.ComponentType<P>,
  RouteType: React.ComponentType<RouteProps> = Route,
  options: Partial<TRoute> = {},
  wrapperProps: P = ({} as unknown) as P
) {
  return function RouteWrapperResuslt({
    component: RouteComponent,
    path,
    exact,
    ...rest
  }: RouteWrapperProps<P, Partial<TRoute>>) {
    return (
      <RouteType
        path={path}
        exact={exact}
        {...options}
        component={(props: P) => (
          <Wrapper {...wrapperProps || {}}>
            <RouteComponent {...rest} {...props} />
          </Wrapper>
        )}
      />
    );
  };
};
```

But this line errors:

```
<Wrapper {...(wrapperProps || {})}>
  <RouteComponent {...rest} {...props} />
</Wrapper>
```

With this error

```
Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'P'.
  '{ children: Element; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dependency-array-tnryz) with a full example

Comment: The error is self explanatory. If you do `wrapComponentInReduxForTesting<{ a: string }>()` then `{}` is not a valid initial value for `props`

Comment: and this got marked down because...........

Comment: You might want to turn the code into a [mcve]. Otherwise the fix is to just make `props` an optional parameter, since it is unused in the body of the function.  And since the return type doesn't depend on `P`, I'd suggest making the function non-generic and replacing `P` with `unknown`.  Plus, the above code is an error all the way back to at least 2.4.  If you upgraded from a version in which that code had no error, it probably has [lots of other issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes).  Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are passing an empty object, why don't you just cast it as an alternative?? I think this should work for you:

```
  Wrapper: React.ComponentType<P | {}>, // Line 23 index.tsx
```

The `{}` type will only allow an empty object, so it should cover your two cases well.

Comment: thank you.  Totally missed using a union in the generic type